# How to: Create Thumbnail Images in c++ windows forms>

Tags: c++, winforms, graphics

I want to code to create Thumbnail images for my tool tip control using  c++ in windows forms.

Yes did research still getting errors..

```
Image^ picture;     
picture->GetThumbnailImageAbort callback ;
callback =  gcnew picture->GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

picture("image.jpg");
Image^ pThumbnail = picture->GetThumbnailImage(50,50,callback,gcnew IntPtr());  
e->Graphics->DrawImage(pThumbnail,10,10,pThumbnail->GetWidth(),pThumbnail->GetHeight());
```

I am getting Following Errors-
left of '->GetWidth' must point to class/struct/union/generic ,
'pThumbnail' : undeclared identifier,
'callback'   : undeclared identifier,
'GetThumbnailImageAbort' : undeclared identifier

function call missing argument list; use  to create a pointer to member
even though i did it and declared all properly.

I am trying to code from Below but in c++:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: *Please give me teh codez*. - um... Did you do any research on this *at all* ?

Comment: Yes did research and getting errors..  picture->GetThumbnailImageAbort callback ;
    callback =  gcnew picture->GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
              
    picture("C://Users//Public//Pictures//nature.jpg");
    Image^ pThumbnail = picture->GetThumbnailImage(50,50,callback,gcnew IntPtr());
    e->Graphics->DrawImage(pThumbnail,10,10,pThumbnail->GetWidth(),pThumbnail->GetHeight());

Comment: What kind of errors ? Edit your question and insert relevant error messages.